# Как подключить в telegram боте на Python время?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Как подключить в telegram боте на Python время? Если к примеру я хочу чтобы человек писал "Сколько сейчас время?", то бот отвечал сколько сейчас время по МСК.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю стоит использовать библиотеку `datetime`, в которой есть функция `now`.

Если вы собираетесь писать бота с помощью библиотеки `pyTelegramBotAPI`, то задача решается следующим образом: в `message_handler` по запросу "Сколько сейчас времени?" необходимо будет использовать функцию `bot.reply_to(message, "Время: " + str(datetime.now()))`

Comment: это предполагает, что сервер, на котором запущен бот, использует московское время. Вместо этого, можно явно нужное время получить: `DT.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow'))` где выполнено `import datetime as DT` и `pip install pytz`

Comment: у меня показывает ошибку в now и не работает помогитепожалуйсто

Answer (score 0):

Используйте модуль `datetime`

```py
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now)

#Так же можно отформатировать вывод
now_formatted = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(now_formatted)

#Если нужно смещение по времени по UTC
offset = datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
timezone = datetime.timezone(offset)
now_with_offset = datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone)
print(now_with_offset)
```

```
%a — будний день сокращенно (Пн, Вт,…)
%A — будний день полностью (Понедельник, Вторник,…)
%w — будний день, как десятичное число (1, 2, 3,…)
%d — день месяца в числах (01, 02, 03,…)
%b — месяцы сокращенно (Янв, Фев,…)
%B — название месяцев полностью (Январь, Февраль,…)
%m — месяцы в числах (01, 02, 03,…)
%y — года без века (19, 20, 21)
%Y — года с веком (2019, 2020, 2021)
%H — 24 часа в сутки (с 00 до 23)
%I — 12 часов в сутки (с 01 до 12)
%p — AM и PM (00-12 и 12-00)
%M — минуты (от 00 до 59)
%S — секунды (от 00 до 59)
%f — миллисекунды (6 десятичных чисел)
```